# Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I need to verify my string contains 1 or more numbers and 1 or more alpha characters.  This string can also have other characters like @#$%%#.  etc.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression for something like this - write a validator:

```
public boolean validate(String val) {
    int len=val.length();

    if(len>=8) {
        boolean alp=false,dgt=false;
        for(int xa=0; xa<len; xa++) {
            char chr=val.charAt(xa);
            alp|=Character.isLetter(chr);
            dgt|=Character.isDigit (chr);
            if(alp && dgt) { return true; }
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If by numbers you mean digits, then you could try `\A(?.*\d.*[a-zA-Z].*|.*[a-zA-Z].*\d.*)\z`

Basically, this matches either of the following:

- any characters (or none), followed by a digit, followed by any characters (or none), followed by a letter, followed by any characters (or none)
- any characters (or none), followed by a letter, followed by any characters (or none), followed by a digit, followed by any characters (or none)

Don't forget to double up your backslashes in your pattern strings :)

You could get it to also match numbers in general (i.e. not just digits) by replacing `\d` with a suitable regex, but what that regex actually is depends on what you're trying to match - more info would be useful.

Comment: Hey Mac, thanks for the response.  I'm trying to validate a password entry.  It must have a length greater than 8 and it must contain atleast one digit and one alpha character

Comment: @c12: then I believe that should do the job (unless I've totally lost the plot... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can verify that in Java with the following code:

```
if (input.matches("(?=.*\\d)(?=.*\\p{L}).+") {
  // match
}
```

It tests that it's at least one digit and at least one unicode letter. It uses positive lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

`^(?=.*\d)(?=.*\D).{8,}$` - matches string with 8 or more chars and contains atleast one number and atleast one non-numeric char.

Answer (score 0):

```
\d.*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z].*\d
```

you don't have to check what is before your first letter or digit as well as what comes after your last letter/digit